# How to enable the existing spring security for a given Servlet?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have a servlet deployed
Myservlet.java

```
@Configurable
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    MyService service;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws javax.servlet.ServletException{
        super.init(config);
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    //Do something here
    }
```

Now the security for this is enabled in web.xml as :

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>myServlet</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/myUrl/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

But where this spring application deployed already has a spring security enabled via `@EnableWebSecurity`

The controllers deployed in the spring application are all correctly getting authenticated as expected. But the servlet is not authenticating with spring security. I believe what's mentioned in the  is stopping it from authenticating.

How do i make the servlet work with Spring security ?

Edit 1:
Spring security configuration: (Note that this is not syntactically correct) but user/role and datasource are all correct in my code. It's working fine for other REST apis deployed in spring application

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    
        String user_query = "select user from userTable where id=9999";
    
        String role_query = "select role from roleTable where id=6666";
        logger.info("Using the following query for role : " + role_query);

        auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource) //Datasource is injected to this class
                .usersByUsernameQuery(user_query)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(role_query);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("myrole")
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(runAsAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Autowired
    protected RunAsManager runAsManager() {
        RunAsManagerImpl runAsManager = new RunAsManagerImpl();
        runAsManager.setKey("MyRunAsKey");
        return runAsManager;
    }
```

Comment: If you're using full Spring, why are you hand-writing servlets instead of using Spring MVC?

Comment: @Sach106 Your configuration looks fine. `.anyRequest().hasRole("myrole")` should work for your servlet. But remember, if you are useing basic authentication, your browser is sending credentials with every request automatically. So if you are logged in with an user with role `myrole`, you can access your servlet.